# What do you need for the treasure maps?

Tags: fallout-76

(SPOILERS)

So together with some friends, I've been playing the beta for a few hours last night and I stumbled upon a treasure map. Being a real Dora the explorer I went and followed the treasure map.

[image]

Assuming X marks the spot, I went and looked on the map for the big tower on the left. I found it near the tracks which also happened to show up on the puzzle map.

[image]

Now we've searched every container, tipped railcars and bush there was in that area from the metal arch till the river below and we came up empty.

My question would be, would I need something like a shovel to dig up 'something' or did we really miss something?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Watching [this YouTube video](https://youtu.be/HrvBKG8BKvo?t=228), it does not seem like you need any special item.  Instead, there should be a special dirt mound that you can interact with by pressing the "Use" button on it.  Upon digging the pile of dirt up, the treasure map will removed from your inventory and you will receive your treasure.

The mound of dirt in this case looked like a grassy mound with some rocks on it.  I assume it would look either like this, or similar to this:

[image: Dirt]